# Kafka 2.1 metrics with AdminClient

Tags: apache-kafka

I am using AdminClient for kafka monitoring. We are using SASL and have authorizer plugin. The user I am using for getting data from this topic is given access and I am able to get other details like offset, lag, etc. But, I am unable to execute describeConfigs.

**Code:**

```
final Collection<ConfigResource> resources = new ArrayList<>();
resources.add(new ConfigResource(Type.TOPIC, "topic1"));
final Map<ConfigResource,Config>configMap=
adminClient.describeConfigs(resources).all().get();
```

**Error:**

> java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException:
>   org.apache.kafka.common.errors.TopicAuthorizationException: Not
>   authorized to access topics: [Topic authorization failed.]

Am I missing anything?

Comment: show the complete code with ssl configs

Comment: "The user I am using for getting data from this topic is given access", can you explicitely list the authorizations this user has?

Comment: I think, i found the solution. The user should be given describeconfigs access.